# Installation error of ruby 2.1.0 on mac rbenv

Tags: ruby, macos, rbenv

I'm new to ruby and here's the error that I'm getting when trying to install ruby 2.1.0 using rbenv

```
rbenv install 2.1.0
Downloading yaml-0.1.6.tar.gz...
-> http://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/7da6971b4bd08a986dd2a61353bc422362bd0edcc67d7ebaac68c95f74182749
Installing yaml-0.1.6...

BUILD FAILED

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/2_/vvtd73rs7bgbd4jd_qv22r9c0000gn/T/ruby-build.20140801132551.77312
Results logged to /var/folders/2_/vvtd73rs7bgbd4jd_qv22r9c0000gn/T/ruby-build.20140801132551.77312.log

Last 10 log lines:
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... no
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/var/folders/2_/vvtd73rs7bgbd4jd_qv22r9c0000gn/T/ruby-build.20140801132551.77312/yaml-0.1.6':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
```

Comment: If you read the error, it says that you need to get a `C` compiler.

Comment: I don't know how you install ruby-build. If installed using homebrew, all dependencies should be installed, and the error cannot occur. BTW, install osx commandline tools at the very first.